# Bold math symbol in caption

Tags: table-of-contents, captions, bold, boldmath, boldsymbol

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[font=bf]{caption}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\newpage
\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{Line plot of SE of $\pmb{\hat\beta_0}$ at cp\pmb{=}0.1, 0.2, 0.3}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I am trying to bold the math symbol`\hat\beta_0` by using `\pmb` but doing this will cause `\hat\beta_0` in my list of figures appear to be bold too. is there a way to bold the math symbol in caption without affecting the caption appear in the list of figures? My caption need to be bold, but to bold the math symbol in caption, I have to use `\pmb`. [image]

Comment: you could use `\caption[no bold]{bold}` but better would be to configure your caption to use `\boldmath` as well as `\bfseries` so the math is bold by default where the text is bold (only use `\bmb` as a last resort, better to use `\boldmath`

Comment: Use the option argument of `\caption`. B.t.w. is there any reason to use `\pmb` rather than `\boldsymbol`?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle where should i add the `\caption[no bold]{bold}`? i tried using `\boldmath` but the `\hat\beta_0` in list of figures still appear in bold.

Comment: @Bernard. what argument should i add in `\caption`?

Comment: I suggested to replace `\pmb` with `\boldsymbol`, but if all you captions are bold, it's much better to follow David Carlisle's advice to add the `\boldmath` directive in `\captionsetup` and use the option `[nobold]`.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 6):

You should use `\boldmath`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}

\DeclareCaptionFont{xbf}{\bfseries\boldmath}
\captionsetup{font=xbf}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\clearpage
\begin{figure}
\caption{Line plot of SE of $\hat\beta_0$ at $\mathrm{cp}=0.1, 0.2, 0.3$}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

For producing the image, I used `\usepackage[paper=a6paper,landscape]{geometry}`.

[image]